# How does European Commission deal with EU countries language subtleties / local context?

Tags: european-union, languages

This is somehow a follow up of [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/27412/why-does-the-romanian-prime-ministers-death-threat-against-a-national-minority) that suggests that European Union should have reacted to a controversial declaration made by an ex-Romanian Prime Minister.

I have noticed that European Commission has sometimes immediate reaction to various declarations made by various politicians. These usually use their native language and sometimes use subtle constructs and/or local context.

I am wondering how can the Commission can tackle these declarations in an efficient manner. Do they have assistants and/or collaborators they fully understand both language subtleties and local context for every EU country? It seems like a small army to fully cover all the EU countries.

Question: How does European Commission deal with EU countries language subtleties / local context?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect as an answer here. The probably use translators. It's not like they're gonna have published guidelines on language subtleties .Why would they need to "tackle these declarations in an efficient manner" to begin with?It's not like they're TV talking heads.

Comment: @Fizz - Yes, I am sure they have translators, but they usually seem to have a good grasp on local politics (e.g. justice problems in Romania, some local TV stations have an anti-justice speech). Can translators cover this or do they also rely on journalists or other type of collaborators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Commission has some [32,000 staff members](https://ec.europa.eu/info/sites/info/files/european-commission-hr-key-figures_2018_en.pdf). Depending on the grade, these speak one to all three official languages but there also recruitment targets in proportionality with every member's country's population *except* in the linguistic services department (where there's no proportionality requirement). Romania currently has a substantial deficit of representation among staff at senior levels; it ranks first by deficit percentage and 2nd by absolute deficit number in this category, according to the [official stats](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:52018DC0377&from=FR).

Answer (score 0):

They have staff who are experts on these issues, and receive briefings from them.

Comment: Agree, but you must develop this in order to be a good answer.